# How to remove all emoji from SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server

How can I remove all the emoji icons from a SQL Server table?

I want to remove all   icons and keep only Hebrew and English Spaces.. letters

In the end I want to keep only Basic Latin (0020—007F) and Hebrew (0590—05FF).

Comment: Do you mean all symbols, including things like https://unicode-table.com/en/1F6BD/ or just those symbols that are specifically in the Emoji group: https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/emoticons/ ? What about characters from other languages, such as https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/gothic/ that aren't Emoji but also aren't Hebrew or English? What about numbers? Puncuation?

Comment: @srutzky In the end I want to keep only Basic Latin (0020—007F)
and Hebrew (0590—05FF). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One fairly simple method would be to use Regular Expressions via SQLCLR. For example:

```
DECLARE @Test NVARCHAR(500),
        @Expression NVARCHAR(500);

SET @Test = N'this' + NCHAR(0x0010) +
            N'$is % a<>TEST,;to}⌡↕strip╞╟╚══¶out_ç_ƒ▀ special-ĳ-೫-chars-舛-დ-א---B';

SET @Expression = N'[^\p{IsHebrew}\x20-\x7F]+';

SELECT @Test AS [Original],
       DATALENGTH(@Test) AS [OriginalBytes],
       SQL#.RegEx_Replace4k(@Test, @Expression, N'', -1, 1, NULL) AS [Cleaned],
   DATALENGTH(SQL#.RegEx_Replace4k(@Test, @Expression, N'', -1, 1, NULL)) AS [CleanedBytes];
```

returns:

```
this$is % a<>TEST,;to}⌡↕strip╞╟╚══¶out_ç_ƒ▀ special-ĳ-೫-chars-舛-დ-א---B        152

this$is % a<>TEST,;to}stripout__ special---chars---א---B                            112
```

The pattern / expression I used — `[^\p{IsHebrew}\x20-\x7F]+` — will match 1 or more characters that are "*not* in the Hebrew Unicode block or in the range of 0x0000 - 0x007F", and replace them with an empty string.

I did also try a pattern of:

```
[^\p{IsHebrew}\p{IsBasicLatin}-[\p{Cc}]]
```

which *should* have been the same since "IsBasicLatin" is the range of 0x0000 - 0x007F, and then substract the Control Characters which have a range of 0x0000 - 0x001F. But for some reason the character class subtraction was not working.

To "clean" the table, you just put it in an `UPDATE` statement like so:

```sql
DECLARE @Expression NVARCHAR(500);

SET @Expression = N'[^\p{IsHebrew}\x20-\x7F]+';

UPDATE tbl
SET    tbl.field = SQL#.RegEx_Replace4k(tbl.field, @Expression, N'', -1, 1, NULL)
FROM   tbl
WHERE  SQL#.RegEx_IsMatch4k(tbl.field, @Expression, 1, NULL) = 1;
```

One difference between this pattern and the one used in my similar answer to [Replace special characters in a column with space](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126127/replace-special-characters-in-a-column-with-space/126144#126144) is the `+` at the end of the pattern here. That is what indicates "one *or more*" of whatever matches the thing to the left of it. In the case here, we are removing characters rather than replacing them individually with another character (such as a space, as was used in the other answer), so we can be a little more efficient and have the Regular Expression group several characters in a row to replace with the empty string.

To be fair, this could also be accomplished in pure T-SQL. You could create a UDF that uses `PATINDEX` to find characters to remove, and use `STUFF(@String, position_from_PatIndex, 1, '')` to remove them individually. Each time you would get the position from `PATINDEX` and exit / break if it returns 0. I don't see that being more efficient than the regular expression, especially since `PATINDEX`, unlike `CHARINDEX`, can't start at a specified location in the string, so you can't just pick up where you left off; you need to rescan the entire string each time you remove a single character.

I just tried the following and it returns the same result string (I just haven't put it into a UDF). Just add it to the end of the test above and run all of it together:

```sql
DECLARE @Position INT,
        @Pattern NVARCHAR(100);

SET @Pattern = N'%[^' + NCHAR(0x0020) + N'-' + NCHAR(0x007F)
                + NCHAR(0x0509) + N'-' + NCHAR(0x05FF) + N']%';
SET @Position = PATINDEX(@Pattern COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2, @Test);

WHILE (@Position > 0)
BEGIN
  SET @Test = STUFF(@Test, @Position, 1, N'');
  SET @Position = PATINDEX(@Pattern COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2, @Test);
END;

SELECT @Test AS [CleanedViaT-SQL],
       DATALENGTH(@Test) AS [CleanedViaT-SQLBytes];
```

returns:

```
CleanedViaT-SQL                                                   CleanedViaT-SQLBytes

this$is % a<>TEST,;to}stripout__ special---chars---א---B          112
```